# Format Value with Delimiter in Nested Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, formatting, nested-forms

I am using Ryan Bates nested_form gem (https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) and running into an issue when it comes to formatting the value on my 'edit' form.

I am currently using this on some of my 'un-nested' form fields and it works great! But when I format the same way on one of the nested elements, I get an '**Undefined Method Error**'

**Code Working on 'Un-Nested Fields'**

```
value: number_with_delimiter(f.object.reserve_price, precision: 2)
```

**Nested Form Fields on Edit**

```
<div id="products">
          <%= f.fields_for :products, :wrapper => false do |product_form| %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group col-md-4">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                <%= product_form.text_field :retail_weekly_price, class: "form-control", placeholder: 'Retail Weekly Rate Card', required: true, (***add value call results in error***) %>
               <div class="input-group-addon">.00</div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
```

**Added Error Log**

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `retail_weekly_price' for #<Location:0x007fd46baa35b0>):
   160:                 <div class="form-group">
   161:                     <div class="input-group col-md-4">
   162:                         <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
   163:                     <%= product_form.text_field :retail_weekly_price, class: "form-control", placeholder: 'Retail Weekly Rate Card', required: true, value: number_with_currency(f.object.retail_weekly_price, precision: 2) %>
   164:                    <div class="input-group-addon">.00</div>
   165:                 </div>
   166:                 </div>
   app/views/locations/_edit_form.html.erb:163:in `block (2 levels) in    _app_views_locations__edit_form_html_erb__1967616523010840695_70275187628360'
   app/views/locations/_edit_form.html.erb:137:in `block in   _app_views_locations__edit_form_html_erb__1967616523010840695_70275187628360'
   app/views/locations/_edit_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_locations__edit_form_html_erb__1967616523010840695_70275187628360'
   app/views/locations/edit.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_locations_edit_html_erb__1956197158500275006_70275237765300'
```

Comment: Can you share the server log with complete error details in your question.

Comment: Thanks @RubyNewbie. One more thing, `retail_weekly_price` field is in which table?

Comment: My Parent table is called: Locations. My child (the one listed) is called: Products........retail_weekly_price is in the 'product' table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
value: number_to_currency(product_form.object.retail_weekly_price, precision: 2)
```

instead of

```
value: number_with_currency(f.object.retail_weekly_price, precision: 2)
```

As `retail_weekly_price` field is in `products` table.

`f.object` would return instance of `Location` which you are referring in `nested_form_for` and as `retail_weekly_price` field is not present in `locations` table, you receive error as

`undefined method 'retail_weekly_price' for #<Location`

`product_form.object` would return an instance of `Product` referred in `fields_for`. You won't have any problem accessing `retail_weekly_price` field through it.

Also, the `ActionView` *helper method* name is `number_to_currency` and NOT `number_with_currency`

Comment: I had tried that previous to this posting. Error: undefined method `number_with_currency' for #<#<Class:0x007fd46f536330>:0x007fd472d90208>